# Is there a way to open a link in new tab in Laravel Filament Richtext editor?

Tags: laravel, rich-text-editor, laravel-filament

I am not able to open the link in new tab from Laravel Filament Richtext editor. I can't see any options to set the _target value or edit the raw source. Has anyone faced this problem?

[image: filament link]

I tried looking into the code and documentation but could not find a way to enable more options for the link button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Filament rich text editor does not support this feature.

Instead, you can use a custom editor like this: https://github.com/mohamedsabil83/filament-forms-tinyeditor

You can find more editors here: https://filamentphp.com/plugins
under Editor tab.